# UNIX - I want to find in a text file the records which have more columns than expected and their line numbers

Tags: file, unix, delimiter

I have a file with pipe delimiter and one record has more columns than expected.

For example:

File NPS.txt

```
1|a|10
2|b|20
3|c|30
4|d|40|old
```

The last column has more columns than expected and I want to know the line number to understand what the problem is.

I found this command:

```
awk -F\; '{print NF}' NPS.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

With this command I know that one columns has one column added but I do not know which one is.

Comment: Do you know the expected number in advance? Can the problem record be the first?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bash script
a) Define a counter variable, starting at 0,
b) iterate over each line in your file, adding +1 to the counter at the beginning of each loop,
c) split each line into an array based on the "|" delimiter, logging the counter # if the array contains more than 3 elements. you can log to console or write to a file.

It's been awhile since I've scripted in Linux, but these references might help:
Intro:
https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-shell-scripting.html
For Loops:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/
Bash String Splitting
[How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)
Making Scripts Executable
https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/musings/make-bash-script-executable/

There may be a good one-liner out there, but it's not a difficult script to write.

Comment: This is not a very precise answer. I'd suggest you add some shell-script to elaborate.